# How to use forked project in Android project

Tags: android, kotlin, maven, jitpack

I forked this project (https://github.com/maxkeppeler/sheets-compose-dialogs), made some modifications on my fork and pushed my commits.

I do not want to wait for the owner to accept or not my PR so I want to use my own forked project. Whenever I am trying to use Jitpack.io to get a copy, I always stumble on this log (https://jitpack.io/com/github/morganesoula/sheets-compose-dialogs/8e5aeca177/build.log) .

I have tried forcing Jitpack to use Java 11 by adding a jitpack.yml file to the root project and set it with:

`jdk: -openjdk11`

But it doesn't seem to be consider.
Could anyone help please?

Comment: What happens if you run `gradlew publishToMavenLocal` in your local project?

Comment: @Tenfour04 It fails with this error: > Task :calendar:signMavenPublication FAILED

The method called for signing the project is found there https://github.com/maxkeppeler/sheets-compose-dialogs/blob/main/calendar/build.gradle.kts

Comment: I don't see your `jitpack.yml` file in your repository. That should resolve the error you're having during the build. I think the signing issue might be OK on the Jitpack end since Jitpack doesn't sign packages, so it might be able to omit that step. Not sure.

Comment: By the way, you should avoid creating your PR in your main branch. It makes it super messy if your PR isn't accepted right away, because now if your PR code becomes outdated compared to the origin project, you have to merge the origin on top of your changes in your main branch instead of rebasing your changes on the latest state of the main branch. And if you want to do another PR, you'll have to create a branch back at the commit before you diverged on main, and then merge the origin's main on that branch before starting on your new changes.

Comment: Just realized that my jitpack.yml always ended up ignored as I have never added it. Thank you so much for the directions you gave me and your personal tips!